# How to check for element after form been submitted and a new page loaded in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form on my page and a function that I want to call ONLY if the user logs in successfully, else it won't be called (it's a function that tracks whether users can successfully log in). I want to test whether a user has managed to log in by checking that once the form has been submitted, the home page loads successfully and I can check whether a specific element from the home page exists (as if the log in was not successful, nothing from that page will show). The issue is that I don't know how to wait for the next page to load AFTER the form has been submitted. At the moment this code calls the function regardless. I have tried incorporating `document.ready` and `window.load` but still I can't make a breakthrough.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function () {

           if ($('#someHomePageElement').length) {

               alert("hello");
               // Call Function 

           }
    });
```

The issue is that it is not waiting until I either get to the home page or not to check whether the element exists. I am not very experienced with Jquery so apologies if this is a very simple question- any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: for submitting the form use ajax, and based on that you can wait and show other page.

Comment: If you submit your form the normal way, then you can not “wait” for this with any script that is running in the context of the _current_ page - because the result of the form submission will be the _new_ page the server responded with. Anything you want to do with JS on _that_ page, you need to do _from within_ that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that submitting the form loads a new page. That means the code on the current page no longer exists, so that code can't do anything within the context of the new page (since the code isn't there anymore).

Instead:

- Track this server-side, or
- Put the code on the page that loads once the form submits successfully, or
- Submit the form via ajax, and if successful, track the information and then set the location to the new page to load